# Eloquent Javascript, listToArray. Why does my for loop return rest [object] when input array has more than 3 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest

I'm currently working through Eloquent Javascript chapter 4. The exercise asks

> Write a function arrayToList that builds up a data structure like the previous one when given [1, 2, 3] as argument

Using the code below I can get the necessary output - but only when the number of elements in the array is 3 or less.

```
function createNode (value, rest) {
  return {
    value: value,
  rest: rest }
};


function arrayToList(arr) {
  var index = arr.length;
  firstNode = createNode(index,null);
  listBuild = firstNode;

for (i =(index-1); i >0; i--) {
  listBuild = createNode(i,listBuild)
}
```

**Question**
arrayToList([1,2,3]) produces the desired result of "{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }"

arrayToList([1,2,3,4]) produces output of "{ value: 1,
  rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: **[Object]** } } }"

Why does this function generate a rest property of [Object] in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to work fine, so I suspect this is an output issue, not any problem with your code.

If you're using Node.js to test your code, then you've just run into a gotcha with its implementation of `console.log`. In Node.js, `console.log` formats objects using [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), and by default `util.inspect` will only display nested objects to a depth of 2. You can change this by calling `util.inspect` directly and using the `depth` option. You could set it to a higher number, or you can set it to `null` for unlimited depth:

```
var util = require('util');
var result = arrayToList([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(util.inspect(result, { depth: null }));
```

Comment: I am indeed using Node.js and this resolves my issue. Thanks!